# Excel won't import date string as date serial number. Maybe Locale or text file encoding issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-format

I have a spreadsheet that uses a text file with a date string as the first field. I have no control over the format of the file:

`"Time_Stamp","User_Name","Host_Name"
"31 Jan 2018 8:10:20 PM","AMG","PC03-BACKUP"
"1 Feb 2018 12:43:42 AM","AMG","PC03-BACKUP"`

The Time_Stamp imports into Excel as a date serial number. I copied the spreadsheet to my PC and updated the data connection to pick up the text file from across the LAN. Both copies of the spreadsheet worked fine for months.

Two weeks ago I had to reinstall windows and Office on the second PC. Since then Excel imports the field as a text string which breaks the spreadsheet.  I've tried rebuilding the text file, re-copying the spread sheet, comparing locale and date formats etc on the 2 pcs, but can't fix it.

Both PCs Windows 10, one Excel 2016, one Excel 2007 tho I don't think that's relevant

Any suggestions?

Comment: is it possible to update the spreadsheet that does the import to deal with dates as strings and convert them?  Also have you tried Text to columns as an in place update to the import?  not sure if the later is an option.  Does your "system" date format match the format of the imported date string?

Comment: The spreadsheet has been in use for a couple of years. I could update it - but I'd rather understand what happened :-/  The system 'short date' format date on both pcs is like the file 'dd mmm yyyy'. Time format on both is 24h hh:mm.

Answer (score 0):

I did a global find/replace on the input file to change " 201? " to "-201? "
This changed

> "31 Jan 2018 8:10:20 PM"

to

> "31 Jan-2018 8:10:20 PM"

That was enough to tell Excel the field was a datevalue and it was imported as a date serial number not as text.

New records are still added to the file with spaces not hyphens - but excel handles them correctly now.